# OCaml function to evaluate addition and subtraction

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I'm currently trying to write an OCaml function that will evaluate expressions and return a Boolean value. I've tried to do research online, and the closest answer that I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978077/ocaml-function-to-evaluate-arithmetic-expressions). However, I'm still having trouble which led me to ask my own question.

Here's the basic code:

```
type equation =
  | True
  | False
  | Equal of exp * exp
and exp =
  | Val of int
  | Add of exp * exp
  | Sub of exp * exp

let rec eval : equation -> bool
= fun f ->
  match f with
  | True -> true
  | False -> false
  | Equal (x, y) -> match (x, y) with
                    | (Val a, Val b) -> if (x = y) then true else false
                    | ((Add (Val a, Val b), c) -> eval (Equal (Val (a + b), c))
```

The program is incomplete, and the recursive call to `eval` in the last line is where I got stuck. A specific input example that I've thought of is:

`eval (Equal (Add (Add (Val 1, Val 2), Val 3), Val 6))`

This should evaluate to `true`, since the two `Add`'s add up to 6, and `Equal` compares `Val 6` with `Val 6`. The trouble that I'm experiencing is how to recursively call the function to evaluate the second `Add` inside the expression, so that `Add (Val 2, Val 2)` first evaluates to `Val 3`, then the first `Add` adds `Val 3` with `Val 3`. The program that I've written right now only evaluates one of the two `Add`'s.

Is there anything that I should be thinking of or keeping in mind? Any feedback is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Why not `Equal (x, y) -> eval_exp(x) == eval_exp(y)`? Doing both in one is uncomfortable, as you're finding...

Comment: Hey @Amadan thanks for the feedback. I've tried that as well, but unfortunately I get a type error that says "this has type exp but type equation was expected."

Comment: You have two types; so two evaluating functions would be needed. Note that I didn't use `eval`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Thanks for clarifying. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Amadan mentioned, it's easier to define a function that would first evaluate expression to an int `eval_exp: exp -> int`. Then you can just evaluate both expressions in the tuple `Equal(e1, e2)` and compare them (`eval: equation -> bool`).

You also do not need values True and False in type `equation`, because you can just return bool from function without pattern-matching. Note that you could need True and False if you passed those, for some reason, again to `eval` function.

```
type equation =
  Equal of exp * exp
and exp =
  | Val of int
  | Add of exp * exp
  | Sub of exp * exp

let rec eval (e: equation) : bool =
  let rec eval_exp e =
    match e with
    | Val i -> i
    | Add (e1, e2) -> (eval_exp e1) + (eval_exp e2)
    | Sub (e1, e2) -> (eval_exp e1) - (eval_exp e2)
  in
  match e with
  | Equal (e1, e2) ->
      if (eval_exp e1) = (eval_exp e2)
      then true
      else false
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of converting `exp` to `int` before. Your tip allowed me to solve the problem. :)